# Absolute Digital Encoder Speed measurement

Tags: control-engineering, motors

I am using a 16-bit absolute magnetic encoder and I get the position from SSI 3 wire, I mean digital outputs for my position control application. I have a problem with getting accurate speed data. I am trying to get speed data from position derivation with a digital filter but nevertheless, my speed data is not accurate and there is too much noise, hence I am not controlling the motor as well.

I have checked some articles and forums but I couldn't find anything about speed measurement with digital outputs. There are a few methods like the T method and the M method but they are using for pulse outputs. Is there any method for estimating or calculating the speed for absolute digital outputs encoders for low-speed applications?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE. How do know that there is too much noise? What type of mitigation measures have you applied to reduce or eliminate noise? What is the part number and vendor of the magnetic encoder? Can you please post a picture of the setup?

Comment: Encoder data sheet.

Comment: Why do you need to know the velocity? The reason you get to much noise is because you are differentiating it. suppose the noise is any random number between 1 and -1. if you take the difference, the largest change you can possibly measure is 2 (from -1 to 1) divided by the timestep. This likely overshadows your rather slow position change. To solve this you could either apply a low pass filter over the measurement and then differentiate or use other methods that do not require a velocity estimate or can observe it using a model and the measured position.